# Importing files to database with folders as categories ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, import, filesystems

Now this seemed like a fairly trivial task but I haven't found any related replies to it.

I have a large set of files organized inside folders wich I need to import to a database (not the files themselves as varbinary, just path and relevant file data), including a Category and subcategory that should be infered from the folder and subfolder the file is in:

```
\\OBJECT ID\CATEGORY\SUBCATEGORY\FILE
```

I don't want to provide a answer in advance - I'd like to know if there is a simple way of doing this, or if I'll have to iterate all the folders keeping variables while scanning files inside said folder, etc etc.

Some code:

```
public void ImportFileSystemToDatabase()
    {
        string fileImportFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileImportPath"];

        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fileImportFolder);

        var folders = dirInfo.GetDirectories();
        var files = dirInfo.GetFiles();

        var fsItems = new List<FileAttachment>();

        foreach (var folder in folders)
            fsItems.Add(new FileAttachment(folder));

        foreach (var file in files)
            if (file.Extension != ".db")
                fsItems.Add(new FileAttachment(file));

    }
```

FileAttachment.cs:

```
public class FileAttachment
{
    public FileAttachment(FileInfo file)
    {
        this.Name = file.Name;
        this.FullName = file.FullName;
        this.Size = file.Length;
        this.CreationTime = file.CreationTime;
        this.LastAccessTime = file.LastAccessTime;
        this.LastWriteTime = file.LastWriteTime;
        this.IsFolder = false;
    }

    public FileAttachment(DirectoryInfo folder)
    {
        this.Name = folder.Name;
        this.FullName = folder.FullName;
        this.Size = null;
        this.CreationTime = folder.CreationTime;
        this.LastAccessTime = folder.LastAccessTime;
        this.LastWriteTime = folder.LastWriteTime;
        this.IsFolder = true;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public long? Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastAccessTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastWriteTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsFolder { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int AdjudicatedRealEstateId { get; set; }
```

DB Spec(ish)

```
SELECT [DocumentFileId]
  ,[MimeType]
  ,[FileName]
  ,[Active]
  ,[CreationDate]
  ,[CreationUser]
  ,[UpdateDate]
  ,[UpdateUser]
  ,[FilePath]
  ,[CategoryId]
  ,[SubCategoryId]
  FROM [DocumentFile]
```

Comment: Can you show what you did? Maybe you are on the efficient right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only those few fields in db then you don't need to iterate all the folders. Instead, you could use Directory.GetFiles() to get list of specific files (e.g. only *.docx, etc) in all subfolders

```
var ff = Directory.GetFiles(fileImportFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var f in ff)
{
    // f is a full path of the file
    Response.Write(f.ToString());

    // use FileInfo to get specific attributes   
    var i = new FileInfo(f);
    Response.Write("SubCategoryId=" + i.Directory.Name);
    Response.Write("CategoryId=" + i.Directory.Parent.Name);
    Response.Write("UpdateDate=" + i.LastWriteTime.ToString());
    ...
}
```

Comment: This sems like a very straightforward method - gonna develop on that and provide feedback in a bit :-)

Comment: There is one thing missing tho: When a file is in a parent folder, I have to assume it doesn't have a category (or sub category) and will have those set as null. So I have to get how "deep" in the filesystem the file is. Gonna look into that.

Comment: As a quick tip - you could compare `Path.GetDirectoryName(f)` with the full path of your folder, if known. If path is not known or you have many folders, you could count number of folders in the path using `Path.GetDirectoryName(f).Split('\\').Count()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the almost finished method base on reply given, just so if anyone has a similar question in the future.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Import files from filesystem to the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>This is a heavy one-time operation. If used on a job, it should run off-peak</remarks>
    public void ImportFileSystemToDatabase()
    {
        string fileImportFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileImportPath"];
        string fileStorage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileStoragePath"];

        var filesToImport = Directory.GetFiles(fileImportFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var filePath in filesToImport)
        {
            var file = new FileInfo(filePath);

            string[] treePath = filePath.Replace(fileImportFolder, "").Split('\\');

            DocumentFile newDocument = new DocumentFile
            {
                MimeType = file.Extension,
                FileName = file.Name,
                Active = true,
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                CreationUser = "IMPORT",
                FilePath = fileStorage + "\\" + file.Name
            };

            //Lets contextualize the document to the object Id
            int adjReId = Convert.ToInt32(treePath[1]);
            //Context goes here

            if (treePath.Count() == 4)
            {
                //Lets set the Category
                newDocument.CategoryId = CreateDocumentCategory(treePath[2], (int)LookupTypes.DocumentCategories);
            }

            if (treePath.Count() > 4)
            {
                //Lets set the Category
                newDocument.CategoryId = CreateDocumentCategory(treePath[2], (int)LookupTypes.DocumentCategories);
                //Lets set the SubCategory
                newDocument.CategoryId = CreateDocumentCategory(treePath[3], (int)LookupTypes.DocumentSubCategories);
            }

            file.CopyTo(fileStorage + file.Name);

            InsertDocumentFile(newDocument);
        }
    }
```

On to optimize category detection now...